# Enlarge clicked image irrespective to position of other images

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to enlarge clicked image and I am getting images by AJAX.

I tried to use class `img-wrap` in JavaScript:

```js
$('.img-wrap').css('transform','scale(40,20)');
```

but this enlarges all the images and I have about 20 images on my page.

**AJAX page:**

```php
<?php
        sleep(1);
        $c=mysql_connect("localhost", "abc", "xyz");
        mysql_select_db("root");

        $sql = "select * from image2 ";
        $qc = mysql_query( $sql ) or die( mysql_error() );              
        $count = 0;
        while( $ans = mysql_fetch_array( $qc ) ) {
            $title=ucwords($ans['EVENT']);
            print " 
               <div class='img-wrap' id='$count' onclick='big(this.id)'>
                <img id='display_img' src='slider_images/$ans[img]' draggable='false'>
               </div>";
            $count++;
        }
?>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```js
function big( z ) {
    $(this.id).css('transform','scale(40,20)');
    $(this.id).css('-webkit-transform','scale(40,20)');
    $(this.id).css('-moz-transform','scale(40,20)');
    $(this.id).css('-ms-transform','scale(40,20)');
}
```

Comment: Do you have a working demo (http://jsfiddle.net, http://placehold.it)?  PHP code is not useful, we need the generated HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#img-wrap')
```

selects an id called img-wrap

```
$('.img-wrap')
```

selects the class

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

```
function big(z) {
    $(z).find('img').({
        'transform','scale(40,20)',
        '-webkit-transform','scale(40,20)',
        '-moz-transform','scale(40,20)',
        '-ms-transform','scale(40,20)'
    });
}
```

(You can put more than one CSS property in the CSS function by making it an object ({}).
Also, your images all have the same ID which is invalid. Every ID needs to be unique.

Comment: His PHP says: `<img id='display_img'` which makes them not unique. The `div` ID is unique, but the image inside is not.